# Where to place exterior 120volt for water heater

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have an interior wall outlet around the location on the picture... lower on the wall. I need an outlet for the water heater. Would you suggest I drill directly through the brick where the outlet is or to put it higher? I also plan to power two water pipe heater wires so maybe having it closer to the water heater would be better...

[image: Interior outlet placement]

Comment: Those water pipe heaters usually do not have a long cord to plug in.  The outlet will need to be close to the pipes you want to protect.  Being outside the wires/cables will need to be wet rated and in conduit.  You can drill where it is easy for you.  Extension cords are not recommended/or allowed for permanent use.  Their use also adds more connection spots to add problems.

Comment: Brand and model of the heater?

Comment: you need to follow manufacturer's instructions. I suspect that they prohibit use of extension cords

Comment: Of course extension cord was just for testing functionality before I setup a real plug.

Comment: For those that missed it this is not an electric water heater,  it a gas heater that needs electricity to function.

Answer (score 6):

Drill where convenient, route conduit to put the receptacle in a good spot. The receptacle should be high enough that rain running down the cord drips off, rather than running into the receptacle. It will need GFCI protection (better done inside the building) and an In-Use Cover. Evidently you'll need either a quad outlet or two duplex outlets since you have plans for 2 pipe heaters as well as the water heater itself to plug in.

Knowing nothing of your constraints I'd consider moving sideways inside the building and having just the receptacle box near the heater with no surface conduit run to be a "cleaner" install, but that may be impractical if the inside wall behind the heater is tiled, or the shower, or both.

Likewise, there's the question of what else is on the circuit with the receptacle you're proposing to come from, and does it make more sense to have a dedicated circuit for the water heater and related line heaters? Indeed, that may be a code requirement (got to go hunting in code, but it would be consistent with other appliance rules. Or it may be required under Article 110 requiring that you follow the manufacturer's instructions, which may call for a dedicated circuit.)

Based, as well as can be quickly done, on your illustrated cord length, the receptacle needs to be somewhere in the lower 2/3's or so of the red circle so the cord can reach it.

[image]

Comment: I think OP is planning to use heat tapes for water pipe freeze protection.

Comment: Yes, the question does state that. Code generally allows "related ancillary equipment" to be on a "dedicated circuit" so long as the ampacity is adequate. They clearly need a proper place to plug the heater itself in, too, given the extension cord it's plugged in to now. Code also explicitly (422.50) requires such heat tapes to be listed.

Comment: I didn't follow the code statements here and thank you for the very thorough explanation. I agree on running a new receptacle to make it cleaner on the outside. Did it mention the heater needs a dedicated outlet? I'm pretty sure this device uses very little electricity so I wouldn't be interested in paying an electrician to run a new line from the breaker box.